# How I can configured Groogle in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I haven´t much experience with Ubuntu and I need to configure a Groogle in Ubuntu server.
I would like to help me with some detailed explanation to perform this task, please.

Comment: This? http://groogle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Please give details

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers
the Documnentation of groogle.sourceforge.net  is broken u_u

but in the sourceforge.net forum found some information about Groogle..

Finally managed to install on Ubuntu Server including all dependencies, build the package Groogle and configure PHP for use in a port 80.

It was complex and complicated but succeed.

If you need more info, tell me and I will detail more the processes.